# Recognize full name in namecard

Tags: python, ocr

I am having a problem with my project and I hope that I can be received your helps. I want to save full name from a text which I used OCR to recognize text from an image. How can I do that? I sorry because my English is not well.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: post you sample image , and piece of work that you tried so far .

Comment: to help you start with - start looking into pytesseract module

Comment: My project is use pytesseract to recognize text from image (namecard) and then I have to save the information from text like full name, phone number, email,... I have already saved phone number and email by using regular expression. And now, I do not know how to get the full name from the text to save it.

Comment: The namecard like that https://inchatluongviet.vn/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/inchatluongviet.vn-in-danh-thiep-5.jpg

Comment: How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Remove all numbers, special characters, email etc from the text. What you will end up with is the remaining text. You can then try using **nltk** to find Proper Nouns (NNP).

```
import nltk
nltk.pos_tag(["Tam","Nguyen"])
```

The only issue is that you may get false positives. For instance, if Tam Nguyen is followed by **Chief Technology Officer**, then you would have NNPs for those too. See if this helps narrow down your problem.